# Passing data from the central panel of one window to the central panel of another window

Tags: python, pyqt5

New to PyQt. I am currently trying to find a way to pass data from one window's central panel to another central panel. I made an MRE to experiment and see if it is possible to do so.

This is the code for my main window

```
class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.label = QLabel("Window 1")
        self.dataLabel = QLabel("Data to be passed")
        self.submitBtn = QPushButton()

        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.box.addWidget(self.dataLabel)
        self.box.addWidget(self.submitBtn)

        self.setLaytou(self.box)

    def openSecondwindow(self):
        data = self.dataLabel.text()
        #to open a new window by passing in the abbv
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = SecondWindow
        self.ui.__init__(self.window)
        self.window.show()


        

#main window to encompass all elements set up
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Project List")

        #positioning of window
        #positioning of window
        WinLeft = 100
        WinTop = 100

        #size of window
        WinWidth = 100
        WinHeight = 100
        self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHeight)

        #setting central widget > CenterPanel() which was just made above
        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        #remove oddities
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))

        #styling central widget
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: turquoise;"
            "padding: 0;"
            "margin: 0;"
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEventThred = QApplication([])

    MainApplication = MainWindow()
    MainApplication.show()

    MainEventThred.exec()
```

This is the code for my second window

```
class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.label = QLabel("Data to be set in the label below")
        self.dataLabel = QLabel()
        
        if data:
            self.dataLabel.setText(data)
        else:
            self.dataLabel.setText("I have not changed! Data is not passed over!")

        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.box.addWidget(self.dataLabel)

        self.setLaytou(self.box)
        

        

#main window to encompass all elements set up
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Project List")

        #positioning of window
        #positioning of window
        WinLeft = 100
        WinTop = 100

        #size of window
        WinWidth = 100
        WinHeight = 100
        self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHeight)

        #setting central widget > CenterPanel() which was just made above
        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        #remove oddities
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))

        #styling central widget
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: turquoise;"
            "padding: 0;"
            "margin: 0;"
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEventThred = QApplication([])

    MainApplication = SecondWindow()
    MainApplication.show()

    MainEventThred.exec()
```

I was not able to find any solution to pass data between windows as most of them do not include a central panel from the examples I have seen so I am lost on what to do.

I tried finding examples of solutions but they only deal with window() to window() passing of data without any central panels included in their code.

For my code, I am hoping to pass data into the QMainWindow objects which will further push the data into the CentralPanel objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question doesn't explain what data you want to pass, how or when, nor what you want to do with it, so we can't really tell you more than suggest you to do some research on signals and slots. Besides, your code is quite confusing (and has typos, like `setLaytou`), not to mention that `self.ui.__init__(self.window)` which is a **terrible** idea and makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforcing the words `@musicamante`, do a search for signals and slots.
Assuming I understand what you're looking for....
A less than elegant alternative is to pass the QMainWindow that sends the data, as an argument to the QMainWindow that receives the data.

Below is a working example of the alternative.
Hope this helps

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QStyleFactory 
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


class CenterPanel_1(QWidget):

    sig = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel("Window 1")
        self.dataLabel = QLabel("Data to be passed")
        self.submitBtn = QPushButton()
        self.submitBtn.clicked.connect(self.passingData)

        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.box.addWidget(self.dataLabel)
        self.box.addWidget(self.submitBtn)

        self.setLayout(self.box)

    def openSecondwindow(self):
        data = self.dataLabel.text()
        #to open a new window by passing in the abbv
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = SecondWindow
        self.ui.__init__(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def passingData(self):
        print('here_1')
        self.sig.emit('Hi')
        

#main window to encompass all elements set up
class MainWindow_1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Project List")

        #positioning of window
        #positioning of window
        WinLeft = 100
        WinTop = 100

        #size of window
        WinWidth = 100
        WinHeight = 100
        self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHeight)

        #setting central widget > CenterPanel() which was just made above
        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel_1()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        #remove oddities
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))

        #styling central widget
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: turquoise;"
            "padding: 0;"
            "margin: 0;"
        )


class CenterPanel_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, ma_1):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel("Data to be set in the label below")
        self.dataLabel = QLabel()
        
        '''
        if data:
            self.dataLabel.setText(data)
        else:
            self.dataLabel.setText("I have not changed! Data is not passed over!")
        '''
        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.box.addWidget(self.dataLabel)

        self.setLayout(self.box)

        ma_1.CenterPane.sig.connect(self.changeLabel)

    def changeLabel(self, newLabel):
        print('here_2')
        self.dataLabel.setText(newLabel)

        
#main window to encompass all elements set up
class MainWindow_2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ma_1):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Project List")

        #positioning of window
        #positioning of window
        WinLeft = 100
        WinTop = 100

        #size of window
        WinWidth = 100
        WinHeight = 100
        self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHeight)

        #setting central widget > CenterPanel() which was just made above
        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel_2(ma_1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        #remove oddities
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))

        #styling central widget
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: turquoise;"
            "padding: 0;"
            "margin: 0;"
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEventThred = QApplication([])

    ma_1 = MainWindow_1()
    ma_1.show()
    
    ma_2 = MainWindow_2(ma_1)
    ma_2.show()

    MainEventThred.exec()
```